# Generating URL for an angular route from controller

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core

Is there a simple way of generating a URL in a .NET Core controller for an angular route? My angular route is a constant and the angular app is on the same origin as my .net app.

I made it work, but I'm not sure if it's a correct way to do that:

```
var baseUrl = $"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host.Value}{Url.Content("~/my-angular-route")}"; // <-- this one
var urlWithQueryParams = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(baseUrl, queryParams);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your Angular and web api hosed on the same domain ?

Comment: Yes sir, it is on the same domain.

Comment: So this `var baseUrl = $"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host.Value}/my-angular-route"` should work?

Comment: Yes it does. But that's my question if it's a solid solution, or there is a better option here?

Comment: Nope. because `Url.Content` is for route registered for ASP.Net Core and not for Angular.